# Using wrapper around a generic object, instead of specific objects

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a design question im not too sure on. Say i have this "policy" sort of like a someone have car insurance or something.

There are tons of different kinds of policies that pop up all the time, so like earthquake, or trucking, or like drone, etc. I want this to be generic so they all sort of fit into this object. I was thinking of storing most of the details  in a string hashmap.

```
public class Policy
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 20130901L;

    private String policynumber;
    private int policyId;
    private String pendingDocType;
    private int transactionTypeId;
    private List<Integer> lobs;
    private List<Integer> markets;
    private Insured insured;
    private Agent agent;
    private Map<String, Location> locations;
    private Map<String, String> details;
}
```

Then for each different type, i create a wrapper class that extends policy with methods for accessing fields according the the type that it is. So if its a drone, i would have methods like

```
getAnnualFlightDistance()
{
    return details.get("flightdistance");
}
getAnnualPremium()
{ 
    // Some method to calculate the current money spent on drone
}
```

But just have helper methods around the main Policy class.

I would make them member variables for each field attached to it, but they're always changing variables a new things being added, i thought having just like a bin for the terms would allow for a constant evolving object.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @jaco0646 haha you're right, i never specifically asked the question. Was asking for design advice on how to structure multiple classes around a generic class, and if using wrappers with methods was the right design practice to use.

Comment: In that case I would say, "_prefer composition over inheritance_."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO If you need to use those fields for some business operations as in the getAnnualPremium case I would suggest to use explicit attributes.

Keeping everything as generic as possible may sound tempting at first but in the long run, as you add/remove/change fields, change the calculations,validations etc having explicit fields is going to be much more useful and easier to maintain than having a map of strings

Comment: Okay, ill try remapping the map to explicit fields. The thing is its like a contantly evolving object. There are always new things being added to it. but you're right the maintenance in the long run will be a lot easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have one base class called policy with common fields and methods between all polices, and for any polices that need other specific methods create an interface and make that specific policy implements it, this way your system will be simpler and extendable.

Comment: Awesome, that is semi what i was thinking, but wasn't 100% sure what route to go, Thank you for the insight.